# Firefox ignores absolute positioning in table cells

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-position

I am trying to absolutely position an element inside a table cell.
The TD has `position:relative` and the element has `position:absolute`.

This works great in all browsers except in Firefox where it is positioned relative to an ancestor relative container.

You can see this reproduced in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ac5CR/1/

Does anyone know if I miss some CSS setting that can fix that in Firefox?

Comment: In firefox the green `indicator` div is located in the first row and it should be in the 3rd row as in chrome and IE.

Comment: Looks like you're using [tables for layout](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/everything.html). Are you?

Comment: unfortunalty I do. I am using jqGrid which uses tables internally. I have to position an indicator inside a cell.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

the  element is not a block element.
add to the  style display:block, you will get the needed behavior.

Comment: It indeed works now although the TD stops behaving like a table cell... I have to specify explicit height for the cell to align with the rest of the cells.

Comment: To expand, the td element's default display value is typically "table-cell" (and given Firefox's support for the "table-cell" display value, this is likely what it defaults to).

Comment: Just ran into this issue - does that mean you can't `positon: absolute` inside a table layout?

Comment: In fact, this is a [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63895), which has already been fixed (since version 31, Firefox will position absolute descendants relative to table cells just like other browsers do).

Answer (score 15):

A possible work around would be to wrap the `position:absolute` element with another `position:relative` div. It requires an extra div, which is lame, but will give you the right result.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pTJUk/

Note -- this still won't give a completely correct result, as the `position:relative` div will be relative to the *text position* in the `td` -- crazy, right? Giving the cell a `vertical-align:top` will make it orient to 0,0, but of course this could be at the cost of other formatting your design requires.

Comment: I was having a similar problem getting an `<a>` to expand over adjacent cells. Putting a `<div style="position:relative;>` inside the `<td>` got everything to work. So far I've encountered no problems across multiple browsers.

Answer (score 1):

It was a very old Firefox bug that have been fixed about 13 years after being reported!

You may refer to the entertaining history here:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63895