# `absolute` child does not relate to `relative` parent when parent is `table-cell` - only firefox

Tags: css, css-position, css-tables

### Situation

html:

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">x</div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

css:

```css
.container {
   display: table;
}

.parent {
   display: table-cell;
   position: relative;
}

.child {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
}
```

### What I expect:

the `.child` should be positioned to the right edge of `.parent`. Works in Chrome.

### What I get in Firefox:

the `.child` is positioned to the right edge of the closest "non static" parent which is has not `display: table-cell`.

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/SYG5k/2

### Question

Why does `display: table-cell` influence the positioning of child elements, or, why is `position: relative` ignored on `table-cell` elements? Can I work around this if I rely on `table-cell`?

Comment: `position: absolute forces display: block` [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896965/css-vertical-align-table-cell-dont-work-with-position-absolute#8897198) & [w3.org article](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)

Comment: @Bondye, but I set `position: absolute` only on the child element where `display: block` is actually what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `position: relative;` in your parent.

So in the code in your question add `position: relative;` to `.container`

Or in your jsfiddle add `position: relative;` to `.parent`

```
.parent {
    height: 150px;
    width: 450px;
    display: table;
    margin-top: 400px;
    background: #bbb;
    position:relative;
}
```

Related : [Firefox ignores absolute positioning in table cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789661/firefox-ignores-absolute-positioning-in-table-cells)  and  [Positioning context on table-cell element in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902743/positioning-context-on-table-cell-element-in-firefox)

About your questioning 'why' : It's no more a 'block' level element. It's a table-cell so positioning will behave in a different way (in this case, with firefox).

See this to [understand deeper about 'tables' behaviors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#model)

http://jsfiddle.net/SYG5k/12

Answer (score 2):

Add a wrapper to your absolute element and make it relative, so you will have something like table-cell > relative wrapper > absolute element

http://jsfiddle.net/SYG5k/13/

```
<div class="rel">
    a 
    <div class="absolute">x</div>
</div>

.foo, .rel {
    position: relative;
}
```

This is a work around I can't explain why it doesn't work normally. Perhaps someone else will answer that for you

Edit : my mistake the wrapper is supposed to wrap everything in the cell, it's what I originally wanted to code, more of a typo. I updated the fiddle above

Comment: unfortunately using a wrapper f*cks up if there is more than 1 absolute child: http://jsfiddle.net/SYG5k/6/

Comment: what do you mean? I see the b at the top. Can you explain please, I viewed it on latest FF on mac

Answer (score 0):

A work around may be to use an inner div with a width and height of 100%, and set that to position:relative;

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">      
<div class="cell foo">
    <div class="cellInner">
        a
        <div class="absolute">x</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cellInner{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Updated JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SYG5k/11/

Comment: I might point out that Huangism's method does not entirely solve the issue, as it displays differently to your original example.The x is now slightly below the a. The wrapper needs to wrap around all of the content inside the .parent div.

Comment: This method also has no issues with more than one absolutely positioned element.

Answer (score 0):

I was adding a popup menu that appears on each row of the table as the user mouses over it when I ran into this FF problem. Based on the very useful info above, I ended up putting a div wrapper *inside* the table cell in each row where I wanted my absolutely positioned popover menu to located, and set its display property to relative. My JS then adds the absolutely position menu *inside* the div as each row is rolled - it has to be a child of the the relatively positioned div, of course. Note that the div will shrink-wrap the td's content rather than filling the td as I expected, but no matter, you then have a relative context, and you can use top and left on the absolutely positioned child element to locate it exactly where you want it with respect to the table cell.